# Какие есть библиотеки для просмотра презентаций powerpoint на сайте (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint

Какие есть библиотеки для просмотра через например iframe презентаций powerpoint на своем сайте?
С сохранением навигации и ссылок.

Answer (score 0):

Есть майкрософтский api:

```
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=<any document - pdf, pptx, docx, etc>" />
```

Там есть ограничение - 10мб. Но есть вероятность, что будут отображаться ссылки (только вероятность - не было возможности проверить)
.

Есть myshared.ru, например, если вам не нужна динамика и презентация у вас загружена заранее.

```
<iframe src='<можно подсмотреть ссылку на embed плеер через код элемента на сайте>' />
```

Но тут http, нет, как я сказал, api для динамичной загрузки на сайт и, наконец, слайды поставляются жипегами (и для производительности плохо, и никакого интерактивного контента, конечно, не будет)...
[И есть поисковик npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=powerpoint). По этому запросу увидел только модули-креейторы, бегло поискав, нашел только [такую штуку под Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer). Не тестировал, сама штука средней тяжести по размеру, но выглядит правдиво.
**Отредактировано:** да, повнимательнее посмотрел на этот модуль - он также просто выдает фрейм с ссылкой на оффис- или гугл-api для просмотра доков. Не думаю, что оно стоит того
Зато вспомнил про гугловский api:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<some document url>&amp;embedded=true" />
```

Здесь тоже ограничение и тоже, похоже, до 10мб. Но зато, *вероятно*, может читать ссылки...